# "as milestone passed"

Tags: british-english, headlinese

"Queen thanks public as milestone passed" what the part of speech of "as" here? Does it equal "Queen thanks public although milestone passed"?

Answer (score 2):

"***As***" here is a **conjunction**, with the meaning "while" or "when" (or "after" due to tenses).

> Queen thanks public *after* milestone passed.

No, it does not mean "although".

Comment: +1 For correct explanation of usage of _as._  Probably worth noting for the OP that the quote overall is an example of headlinese, and is not a complete sentence.

Comment: But the first half of sentence is simple present,and the second one is simple past.the tense is not consistent obviously

Comment: Nothing obvious about that.  There is ***no*** rule in the grammar that says that two parts of the sentence need to have *the **same** tense* or the same *class* of tense (like Present Indefinite and Present Continuous).